# T-SQL: How can you create a table with SELECT?

Tags: oracle, t-sql

In oracle, you can issue:

```
 create table foo as select * from bar;
```

What is the equivalent T-SQL statement?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use [`SELECT INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750.aspx). From MSDN:

> The SELECT INTO statement creates a new table and populates it with
>   the result set of the SELECT statement. SELECT INTO can be used to
>   combine data from several tables or views into one table. It can also
>   be used to create a new table that contains data selected from a
>   linked server.

So:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 INTO newTable FROM existingTable;
```

Answer (score 32):

You can try like this:

```
select * into foo from bar
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to write to the tempdb

```
Select *
INTO #tmp
From bar
```

or to a SQL DB

```
Select *
INTO Temp
From bar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * into dbo.my_table from (
    select col1, col2... coln from bla
)tbl
```